# How do I display multiple list in a table?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have three list i.e, `A`, `B`,`C`. I want to display each list in a column of a table. Like `column A` will have values of list `A`. How do I do that? Thanks for any help!!!

for Example:

```
a[] listA = New List[]{"1","2',"3"};
b[] listB = New List[]{"4","5',"6"};
c[] listC = New List[]{"7","8',"9"};
```

I need to be able to display a table using each list as column values, for example:

```
COL A     COL B    COL C   
1         4        7   
2         5        8 
3         6        9
```

What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose A B C are `list<String>`

Create a wrapper class with all 3 A, B, C  String

```
public Class pageCtrl{
    public List<wrapper> lstWrapper {get;set;}

    public pageCtrl(){
    lstWrapper = new List<wrapper>();
    lstWrapper.add(new wrapper)
    }

 public class wrapper{

    public String A {get;set;}
    public String B {get;set;}
    public String C {get;set;}

    public wrapper(String A, String B, String C){
       this.A = A;
       this.B = B;
       this.C = C;
    }
 }
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="pageCtrl">
  <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstWrapper}" var="wrpr">
          <apex:column>
            {!wrpr.A}
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            {!wrpr.B}
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            {!wrpr.C}
          </apex:column>

         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     <apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: In my scenario in wrapper class `A`, `B`, `C` are no `string`. Its a `list` and those list has to iterated as row.

Comment: list of string.

Comment: create one more wrapper class for A,B,C String and use this wrapper in first wrapper

Answer (score 3):

There is a another way. You can simple create 3 tables inside one table in your VF page. By doing this you can avoid the processing over the collections to store the elements again in the `List<wrapper>`.
Ex:

```
<table> //outerTable
<tr>
<td>
<table></table> //table 1  -Use apex repeat for each <tr> to show element
</td>
<td>
<table></table> // table2
</td>
<td>
<table></table> //table3
</td>
</tr>
</table> //end of outer table
```

Comment: Thanks man for your suggestion. I had figured it out earlier. :)